# Search refinement owsmetadatafacetinfo is empty

Tags: search-results, taxonomy

We are using several taxonomy values that we would like to use in the search refinements.

As I understand the crawled property `owsmetadatafacetinfo` should take care of all taxonomy values and then we can use that for customizing our refinement. The problem is that `owsmetadatafacetinfo` only seems to include values from Enterprise keywords and not our own created term sets.

Have anyone here experienced the same thing?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625183(v=office.14).aspx